# How to write accordion JavaScript in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm a beginner and I'm having a problem in writing my accordion JavaScript code to jQuery.

Here is my JavaScript code

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");  
  });
}
```

Here is the jQuery I tried

```
$(".accordion").each(function(index) {
    $(index).click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle("slow")
    })
})
```

I tried it but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: try toggle class instead of `slideToggle`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```js
$(".acc").on("click", function() {
  $('.acc>p').hide("slow"); // hide all
  $(this).find("p").show("slow"); /// show content
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acc">
  <p style="height: 60px; background: lime; display:none;">Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
<div class="acc">
  <p style="height: 60px; background: lime; display:none;">Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to make a snippet with your code. You don't need to link to a Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to loop through elements using jQuery, it will do for you ;)

```
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
    $(this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

That's all!